# How to tell Jersey Jackson to not serialize one resource?

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I have a REST API implemented using Jersey, I am using the Jackson feature for automatically serialize objects to JSON, there is a special case where I need to return a JSON string that represents an script. As the script can have different unknown structures I cannot just serialize it to an Object, that script comes from a column in a db table. At the same time I have a full Script object that contains all the information of the DB including the script string as a String property.

What I want is to tell Jersey-Jackson not to serialize (skip) the endpoint GET /script/{scriptId}, look at the code:

```
@Path("script")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ScriptResource {
    private ScriptService service;    

    @GET
    @Path("{scriptId}")
    public String getScript(@NotNull @PathParam("scriptId") Integer scriptId) {
        return service.getScript(scriptId); // returns a a valid JSON String 
    }


    @GET
    @Path("full/{scriptId}")
    public Script getFullScript(@NotNull @PathParam("scriptId") Integer scriptId) {
        return service.getFullScript(scriptId); // returns a Script object
    }
}
```

The @Produces annotation is the one that triggers the automatic transformation via Jackson, I would like to configure Jackson and exlude the resource endpoint that I don't want to be converted automatically.

**I don't want to:**

- Use Response as a return type
- Change the Produces annotation to avoid Jackson
- Use a Map as a return type which I would feed by parsing the String

Answer (score 2):

One more option which you can consider in addition to those mentioned by @wasabi, is having a wrapper class for your string which would customize the Jackson serialization so it would not be converted to JSON. That can be done by using the combination of the `@JsonValue` and `@JsonRawValue` annotations on the getter method.

Here is an example wrapper:

```
public class RawJsonString {
    private final String json;

    public RawJsonString(String json) {
        this.json = json;
    }

    @JsonRawValue
    @JsonValue
    public String getJson() {
        return json;
    }
}
```

... then your modified resource method would look as follows:

```
@GET
@Path("{scriptId}")
public JsonRawString getScript(@NotNull @PathParam("scriptId") Integer scriptId) {
    return new JsonRawString(service.getScript(scriptId)); // returns a a valid JSON String 
}
```

Comment: This one could be an option, however in this question I am trying to find how to configure Jersey-Jackson to ignore the resources that I don't want to be converted, that way I don't need to be writing wrappers for every case I could have

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make sure that some fields in `Script` class would not be serialized by Jackson, you could easily do so by annotating such fields with [@JsonIgnore](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html).

If you would like to have more control over the generated JSON, I would implement a custom [JsonSerializer](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html), and refer to it using [@JsonSerialize](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) annotation in your `Script` class. See [this post](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization) for an example.

If you cannot modify `Script` class, you could also implement a [MessageBodyWriter](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html). See [this post](http://programmingitch.blogspot.ca/2014/03/creating-simple-jax-rs-messagebodywriter.html) for an example.

Comment: No, the question is not about ignoring properties in the Object, it is about ignoring the single resource method 'getScript()', I don't want Jackson to serialize the result of that method at all, I want it to be returned as a String but without affecting my other methods which are returning Objects serialized by Jackson.

Comment: @raspacorp You could try the other two options in my answer, where you could customize how `Script`s are serialized without affecting anything else. They would apply to any endpoints that return a `Script`.

Comment: The problem is not about the method returning Script, for that I want Jackson to work normally, the question is about the other method which is not returning a Script it returns a String which is a valid JSON String, so as it is already a JSON I don't want Jackson to convert it. In summary, one method returns a Script object, the other method returns JSON as String.